# Disallow acces to a parent category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, parent, categories

We have several subcategories in one of our Wordpress and only one parent category. We don´t want the users can go to the parent category because it´s empty and ugly.

The issue is...google is indexing the parent category and furthermore, you can write directly the url of the parent category in the browser.

We´ve been trying hacces with these simple sentences (among others), but still does not works

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /WE-WANT-THIS-OFF!!!!!!/
Rewriterule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any other suggestion ?? Thanks in advance people :D !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the rewrite rules below the `RewriteBase` directive as the rules use this base in their matching. Also no need with the rewrite condition as you're just matching a pattern. A sole RewriteRule is sufficient.

Try something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Don't do anything if index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Redirect category
Rewriterule ^category/my-parent-category/?$ http://{{SERVER_NAME}} [R=301,L]

# Pass all other requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks for your help kjetilh...finally I managed to do the work with the plugin called Wp htaccess Control

I guess the problem was Wordpress was replacing several times my anotations in the htacces file (don´t know why)...but this plugin mantain my anotations